# Backspace deletes what's RIGHT of the cursor/caret in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 14 CE and when I hit delete, it deletes what's RIGHT of the cursor/caret!

The only way for me to delete normally is by using shift + delete.

Is this normal?

Comment: You've said "backspace" in the title but "hit delete" in the question. Are you using the words "backspace" and "delete" interchangeably? Are they not two different keys on your keyboard?

Comment: I forgot to clarify that I was using a mac, so I only have a delete key, and not a backspace key. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you press backspace or delete?

I think it's normal, when an editor deletes the characters right from the cursor.

In IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.1 UE, pressing delete causes the right characters to be deleted. Pressing backspace deletes characters left from the cursor.

Have a look at "File" --> "Settings" --> "Appearance & Behavior" --> "Keymap"

Comment: It turns out it was a keybinding issue. I changed a keybinding that resulted in a override of another keybinding, which then led to my issue.

Comment: Rebinding the delete key sounds... unpredictable :)